# Alternative function to (switch without break)

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{

    int price;

    scanf("%d", &price);
    
    switch (price)
    {
    case 1000: // what i want - case pay >= 1000
               // code (no break - intentional)

    case 500: // ....... - case pay >= 500
              // code
    
    default:
               break;
    }
}
```

I'm new to this. Is there any alternative to `switch` without `break` and also able to use comparisons, not constant, in a `switch`?

Comment: There is an alternative. `if/else if/else`. `switch` is the wrong tool for this job. You're trying to fit a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: Do not declare `main` as `void main(void)`. Use `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, or equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, this problem is better suited to consecutive `if` blocks than to a `switch` statement (where the use of *deliberate* fall-through is frowned-upon by many in the C programming world).

However, if you want to divide a number into ranges of fixed-size blocks (in your case, that size is 500), then you can divide your number by that block-size and use the result as the `switch` variable. Also, note that the `default` case doesn't have to be the *final* case – it can be anywhere, even first.

In the below example, because of the fall-through (i.e. no `break;` statements in any of the `case` blocks), the `case 0:` code will be run for *any* input; for inputs less than 500 (i.e. the *integer* division will result in 0), **only** that case will execute. For numbers in the range 500 thru 999 (division will give 1), the `case 1` **and** `case 0` code will run; and, for numbers >= 1000, the `default` case will run, followed by the other two blocks. (This code requires a *positive* value for `price`!)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int price = 0;
    printf("Price: ");
    int s = scanf("%d", &price);
    if (s != 1 || price < 0) {
        printf("Invalid price!\n");
    }
    else {
        switch (price / 500) {
        default:
            printf("Price is >= 1000!\n");
        case 1:
            printf("Price is >= 500\n");
        case 0:
            printf("Price is anything\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As I have said, I would generally not recommend using a `switch` in cases (poor pun) like this; but, that advice notwithstanding, it is then actually quite easy to add extra blocks/conditions, such as code for prices in the 1000 - 1499 range, where you could just insert a `case 2:` block to the code. Furthermore, when the number of 'ranges' becomes sufficiently large (say, more than 3), then it does *arguably* become clearer to use such a `switch`, rather than a chain of `if` statements/blocks.

---

Note: For added clarity – if your compiler supports it (clang and gcc do but I'm not aware of an equivalent for MSVC) – then you can add `__attribute__((fallthrough));` statements wherever you are relying on any (implied) fall-though from one case block to the next. In the code shown above, such statements would be added immediately before the `case 1:` and `case 0:` labels.

Answer (score 1):

Just series of `if` statements then :

```c
if (price >= 1000) {
    // do something
}
if (price >= 500) {
    // do some more stuff
}
```

- You may also want to use `#define` for those magic numbers `(1000, 500 ...)`. Or Enumerate them using `enum`.
- Although `switch()` looks like a function, it's a statement block.

Answer (score 0):

Use chained `if … else` statements:

```
if (1000 <= price)
{
    // Things for price 1000 or more.
}
else if (500 <= price)
{
    // Things for price 500 or more.
}
else
{
    // Things for other cases.
}
```

Comment: I need to print for all cases. Not for one only.

Comment: @Alex: So print for all cases. What is stopping you?

Comment: and remove the `else`s for "no break" equivalence :)

Comment: This one will print for above and equal 1000 case and break there, won't print for next case. I want to run next case too.

Comment: @pmg one thing i did not want to do. Is that the only way?

Comment: @Alex Why not? It makes better sense when reading than switch-cases with fallthrough.

Comment: I kinda suspect a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here.

Comment: @Alex: The code shown will not print anything for any cases, because there are not `printf` calls or other printing code in them. Show all the code you want to have executed, or at least show one instance of each combination of conditions for which you want to have some code executed.

Comment: @pmg I don't know if I was short-sighted or was truly XY problem. Well, at least I learned new term. How do I close this thread? New here, sorry for trouble.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Just needed to remove else. Thanks.